# Randomised Image in array is displaying wronged for image tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, random

***functionality:***

I have set 2 image tags in my html body to be displaying 2 randomised images from an array. Secondly, I have ensured that the 2 displayed randomised images will not repeat itself via the code line  `var Brand = BrandNameArray.splice(random_BrandIndex, 1)[0];`

However, when I do run the code, I have noticed that the second image for the 2nd image tag in the html body is displaying the wrong image. It is displaying an image index of +1.

Meaning:

I have an array_Image = [A, B, C, D, E] and within my console log, it is stated that the randomised image returns 2 images of [0,3], hence rightfully, it should be showing image [A , D] in my image tag of my html body. However, the images that are displayed are [A, E]. The following behaviour has occured quite a number of times even though, it is not consistent.

Could i please get some help on this. Thanks.

I have attached the following code for your perusal.

The following code of `onclick="selectBrand('2');` is called when user clicks on the displayed randomised  generated image, will display a popup image that is also from another array that is appended to `Brand_list.push(random_BrandIndex);`, depending on the image that is being pushed to the temporary store array -> `var Brand_List=[];`

```js
 //Brand Offers
 var Brand_list = [];

 var BrandNameArray = ["lib/img/Brands/A.png", "lib/img/Brands/B.png", "lib/img/Brands/C.png", "lib/img/Brands/D.png", "lib/img/Brands/E.png"];






 //Randomised Brand Offer
 //Auto populate into brand container once randomised
 $('#BrandWinlist > img').each(function(i, img) {

   random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);
   console.log("random_BrandIndex:" + random_BrandIndex);

   //Assign Variable to generate random Brands
   //var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex];
   console.log("Brand:" + Brand);


   var Brand = BrandNameArray.splice(random_BrandIndex, 1)[0];

   Brand_list.push(random_BrandIndex);

   $(img).attr('src', Brand).show();
 });

 console.log("Brand_list:" + "[" + Brand_list + "]");
```

```html
<div id="MainBackground" align="center" style="position:absolute; width:1080px; height:1920px; background-repeat: no-repeat; z-index=8; top:0px; left:0px; margin:auto;">


  <!--Div to show my 2 randomised images-->
  <div class="GameWinBrand_Container">
    <div id="BrandWinlist" class="GameWinBrand_innerScroll">
      <img id="GameBrand_1" style="width:230px; height:230px; top:0px; left:0px; border:0px; outline:0px" onclick="selectBrand('1');">
      <img id="GameBrand_2" style="width:230px; height:230px; top:0px; left:330px; border:0px;" onclick="selectBrand('2');">
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have an array_Image = [A, B, C, D, E] and within my console log, it
>   is stated that the randomised image returns 2 images of [0,3], hence
>   rightfully, it should be showing image [A , D] in my image tag of my
>   html body. However, the images that are displayed are [A, E].

Consider this :

```
[A, B, C, D, E]   Random number : 0, 
so splice(0) [A, B, C, D, E] => [B, C, D, E] Output : A (A is on 0th position)
```

Next,

```
[B, C, D, E] Random Number : 3,
so splice(3) [B, C, D, E] => [B, C, D] Output : E (E is now on 3rd position)
```

That's why the images are `[A,E]` not `[A,D]`.

*P.S : Why were you not confused when the rando numbers were same like : [0,0]?*

> The following behaviour has occured quite a number of times even
>   though, it is not consistent.

It will behave like this, when

```
1st random number < 2nd random number
```

why(?) : Because of the above explanation.

```js
//Brand Offers
var Brand_list = [];

var BrandNameArray = ["A.png", "B.png", "C.png", "D.png", "E.png"];

//Randomised Brand Offer
//Auto populate into brand container once randomised
$('#BrandWinlist > img').each(function(i, img) {
  var flag = false;
  do {
    random_BrandIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * BrandNameArray.length);
    if (Brand_list.indexOf(random_BrandIndex) == -1) {
      flag = true;
      Brand_list.push(random_BrandIndex);
      console.log("random_BrandIndex:" + random_BrandIndex);
      var Brand = BrandNameArray[random_BrandIndex];
      $(img).attr('src', Brand).attr("alt", Brand).show();
    }
  } while (!flag);
});

console.log("Brand_list:" + "[" + Brand_list + "]");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="MainBackground" align="center">


  <!--Div to show my 2 randomised images-->
  <div class="GameWinBrand_Container">
    <div id="BrandWinlist" class="GameWinBrand_innerScroll">
      <img id="GameBrand_1">
      <img id="GameBrand_2">
    </div>
  </div>


</div>
```

Comment: ok, the reason why i have made us of '.splice()' is to prevent an occurrence of this `[0,0]` so that it will never have a repeated image within the  store array of `var Brand_List`. Then I would like to ask, is that splice is not a good method to ensure a singular image to be displayed? it has not occured to me in an event of [0,0] even though i have splice the random array

Comment: see, when you `splice` your array of images, you are removing the image from the array not the index! Indices shift.

Comment: I have also observe some other behaviour in the sense that if i were to input .splice(arrayName, 0); , duplicate images will still be displayed.  So does that mean, that after splicing, i will have to put the element back within the array??

Comment: Refer my updated answer, it shows how to get unique images using random from your array.

Comment: would like to clarify why did you equate `Brand_list.indexOf(random_BrandIndex) ==` to a -1?

Comment: IndexOf returns -1 when it fails the find the searched object. So basically i am trying to find out unique random number. I generate a random number and store it then again generate a random number and store it if and only if it is not present in the array. Thus creating non repeating random indices so the images.

Comment: understood, the store of the random number is through the "flag", correct?